# Fixed table td width in hidden div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to put table to div and set fixed width for columns, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Here you can see example:

```
<div class="content">

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:400px">
            12312312222
        </td>
        <td>
            43fr134f134
        </td>
        <td>
            32d234de234
        </td>
        <td>
            32d234de234
        </td>
        <td>
            32d234de234
        </td>
        <td>
            32d234de234
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


</div>



.table
{
    border:1px solid black;
    table-layout:fixed;
    /*width:400px;*/
}

.table td
{
    border:1px solid black;
}

.content
{
     width:100px;
     overflow:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3h5gB/

Width of first td is 400px but it fits by text size. If I remove div or make the width of div very big it works ok.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your .content has a width of 100, your table will be truncated.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by putting table into div? something like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/3h5gB/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/htdKj/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">

  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>12312312222</td>
      <td>43fr134f134</td>
      <td>32d234de234</td>
      <td>32d234de234</td>
      <td>32d234de234</td>
      <td>32d234de234</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  border:1px solid black;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:800px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table td {
  padding: 2px 0 2px 2px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.table td:first-child {
  width: 290px;
}
```